# Java Spring 4.2.5 Guava Cache Unable to Add Additional @Cacheable Annotations

Tags: java, spring, caching, guava

I'm working on an existing Java 8/Spring 4.2.5 web application and trying to extend its already-working caching, which uses Spring's support of Guava Cache, to more functions in hopes of improving performance.  The application makes use of Spring 4's built-in caching as set up in its CacheConfig file:

**CacheConfig.java**

```
import com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CachingConfigurer;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.cache.guava.GuavaCache;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheErrorHandler;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheResolver;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.KeyGenerator;
import org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig implements CachingConfigurer {

    @Bean
    @Override
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        SimpleCacheManager simpleCacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        GuavaCache cache1 = new GuavaCache("hourCache", CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .expireAfterWrite(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .build());
        simpleCacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(cache1));
        return simpleCacheManager;
    }

    @Override
    public CacheResolver cacheResolver() {
        return null;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public KeyGenerator keyGenerator() {
        return new KeyGenerator() {
            @Override
            public Object generate(Object o, Method method, Object... params) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(o.getClass().getName());
                sb.append(method.getName());
                for (Object param : params) {
                    sb.append(param.toString());
                }
                return sb.toString();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public CacheErrorHandler errorHandler() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Previous declaration of what to cache has been done via annotations:

**ScheduleResponseService.java**

```
@Cacheable(value = "hourCache", unless="#result == null")
public ScheduleResponse getYearsTypeSummary(HttpServletRequest request) {

        ScheduleResponse scheduleResponse = new ScheduleResponse();
        YearsType yearsType = null;

        String exceptionMsg ="Could not retrieve list of summary years for Schedule.";
        scheduleResponse.setMessageText(exceptionMsg);
        try {
            yearsType = scheduleApiClient.getYears(authenticator.getAuthorizationToken(request), SUMMARY);
        } catch (ClientResponseFailure ex) {
            handleClientResponseFailure(scheduleResponse, ex.getResponse(), exceptionMsg);
        } catch (PrivilegedActionException | GSSException ex) {
            handleGenericException(scheduleResponse, ex.getMessage(), exceptionMsg);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            handleGenericResponseException(scheduleResponse, ex.getMessage(), exceptionMsg, request);
        }

        scheduleResponse.setYearsType(yearsType);
        return scheduleResponse;
    }
```

However, when I try to extend the same annotation-based caching declaration for another function in the same Java file that was not previously cached, i.e.:

```
@Cacheable(value = "hourCache")
public ScheduleResponse getTermTypeSummary(HttpServletRequest request, String year, String term, String sess) {

        ScheduleResponse scheduleResponse = new ScheduleResponse();
        TermType termType = null;

        String exceptionMsg = "Sorry! Could not retrieve the " + term.toUpperCase() + " " + year + " term.";
        scheduleResponse.setMessageText(exceptionMsg);
        try {
            termType = scheduleApiClient.getTerm(authenticator.getAuthorizationToken(request), year, term, SUMMARY, sess);
        } catch (ClientResponseFailure ex) {
            handleClientResponseFailure(scheduleResponse, ex.getResponse(), exceptionMsg);
        } catch (PrivilegedActionException | GSSException ex) {
            handleGenericException(scheduleResponse, ex.getMessage(), exceptionMsg);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            handleGenericResponseException(scheduleResponse, ex.getMessage(), exceptionMsg, request);
        }

        scheduleResponse.setTermType(termType);
        return scheduleResponse;
    }
```

I receive a NullPointerException error:

```
webmvc.config.CacheConfig$1.generate(CacheConfig.java:48) org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CacheOperationContext.generateKey(CacheAspectSupport.java:637)
org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.generateKey(CacheAspectSupport.java:490)
org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findCachedItem(CacheAspectSupport.java:434)
org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:336)
org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:302)
org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
webmvc.response.ScheduleResponseService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$952eed68.getTermTypeSummary()
webmvc.courses.controller.ScheduleController.displayScheduleTerm(ScheduleController.java:79)
```

I can add the @Cacheable... annotation to any function to receive the NullPointerException.  I don't understand why I'm unable to extend caching to new functions, since it does not appear extra declarations or annotations have been made to support caching anywhere else in the code.

Can someone point out what I might be doing wrong in going about extending caching this way, and how to correct it?

Comment: What was the previous configuration?

Comment: The previous configuration of the getTermTypeSummary?  That function is exactly the same, I've just added the @Cacheable(value = "hourCache") annotation to the top of it.  The CacheConfig configuration has not been altered, either.  From my understanding, it shouldn't need to be altered to allow for additional caching to occur.

Comment: They aren’t the same, nor will caching actually work. The cache key is are the method parameters and a HttpServletRequest will never be the same, hence rendering caching useless as it will never result in a cache hit.

Comment: The real problem, of you want a try, is your custom keygenerator. It assumes that all parameters are present, when one of them is null it will break.

Comment: Can you clarify what is meant by "They aren't the same"?  In the code I compile, I literally only added the @Cacheable... annotation, so I'm not sure I understand what is meant there.

Answer (score 0):

As M. Deinum stated, the custom keygenerator was the issue.  When the one of the parameters was null, the keygenerator would trigger the null pointer exception.  To correct this, I modified the code to:

```
    @Bean
    @Override
    public KeyGenerator keyGenerator() {
        return new KeyGenerator() {
            @Override
            public Object generate(Object o, Method method, Object... params) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(o.getClass().getName());
                sb.append(method.getName());
                for (Object param : params) {
                    if (param != null) {
                        sb.append(param.toString());
                    }
                }
                return sb.toString();
            }
        };
    }
```

which resolved the null pointer exception for all cases that I've tested so far.